# не валидный json

Tags: php, json

php скрипт загружает html закодированый в json со стороннего сервиса, иногда, по разным причинам приходит не полный ответ(медленное соединение) соответственно json не валидируется стандартными функциями php, например json_decode. Скрипту очень важно знать что пришло, даже если этот ответ получен не полностью. Посоветуйте как достать данные из невалидного json?

Простой пример, ответ json должен содержать 25 ссылок, но json загрузил только 10, и оборвался на 11, как достать эти 10 ссылок?

Comment: посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187576/how-to-determine-whether-a-string-is-valid-json и тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php

Comment: не полностью это вот так что ли `[ 'http://gogle.com', 'http://yandex.ru', 'http://bing'` а дальнейшее тело `'.com', ...., ]'` отсутствует?

Comment: по какой причине  нельзя отправлять повторный запрос, если первый вернул кривой результат?

Comment: да, именно так, только ссылки оформлены в некоторый html код содержащий разные атрибуты, для повторного запроса нету времени, нужно обрабатывать то что есть

Comment: очевидным ответом к данному вопросу будет, что либо вы самостоятельно должны привести обрывок данных к валидному формату, либо нужно найти библиотеку, которая сделает это за вас. Других способов тут очевидно нет и не будет.
Возможно, если требуется обработка строго типизированного файла, то вы сможете выдрать ссылки с их окружением помощью регулярных выражений, вообще забив на Json формат. Если же у вас куча разных данных так приходит, то конечно вариант не пройдет.

Comment: @teran, да решил так и сделать, забив на json регулярной выдеру все ссылки и заменю обратные слеши. Всем спасибо.